# Importing back GIS made grid from Excel?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, excel, vector-grid

I have the following problem: We created a grid and used it's squares as quadrates with an also attached attribute table. As the working areas were far fom each other, we created different sites cutting the grid into pieces, containing different amount of quadrates. Every quadrate contains different data. I used XY tools to export the attribute tables to excel, where joined them into one attribute table. every line contains of cours the 4 coordinates (x min x max y min y max) and would like to import it back to qgis!

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be editing coordinates culumn into WKT format (or creating it):

MultiPolygon (((xmin ymin, xmax ymax, xmax ymin, xmin ymax, xmin ymin)))

Save it as csv and add as delimited text layer. At the import you can choose WKT as geometry definition and select this column.

Next time in similar situation you can export attribute table by selecting all features in attribute tabel, use ctrl+c and paste it into excel. This way you will also copy full WKT of the geometry in excel in case you want to import it again..

Comment: Even easier - as long as you preserve the wkt_geom field in Excel as the _first column_, you can simply copy the table in Excel and **paste** back into QGIS as a new vector layer or temp. layer!

Comment: I will have some extra work with it, but from now on I will use it in this way for the rest of the project, so thank you again Mat!